how to call a method in a template?
I'm trying to do something like this
{{ range .Posts.GetSublistByPagenumber .Number }}
where GetSublistByPagenumber is
func (posts Posts) GetSublistByPagenumber(pageNumber int) Posts { // Рассчитываем индекс начала и конца среза
    fmt.Println("I AM IN GetSublistByPagenumber")
    
    if pageNumber < 1 {
        return posts[0:MAX_POSTS_ON_PAGE]
    }
    
    startIndex := (pageNumber - 1) * MAX_POSTS_ON_PAGE
    endIndex := startIndex + MAX_POSTS_ON_PAGE
    // Проверяем, не превышает ли конец доступный размер
    if startIndex >= len(posts) {
        return []Post{} // Возвращаем пустой срез, если номер страницы вне допустимого диапазона
    }
    if endIndex > len(posts) {
        endIndex = len(posts) // Если конец превышает длину списка, устанавливаем его на длину списка
    }
    // Возвращаем подсписок постов
    
    return posts[startIndex:endIndex]

}

but the code doesn't even go into the GetSublistByPagenumber method !
this is my page context:
func GetPageContext(c *gin.Context, pageNumber int, posts Posts, data string) *Page {
    accessLvl := getAccessLvl(c)
    return &Page{
        AccessLvl: accessLvl,
        Title:     "title",
        Posts:     posts,
        Tags:      t, // список всех тегов
        Number:    pageNumber,
        Data:      data,
    }
}

this is my routing
func SetupRoutes(r *gin.Engine) {
    // Функции, которые будут использоваться в шаблонах
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        "add":                add,
        "GetFirstSymbols":    GetFirstSymbols,
        "SplitString":        SplitString,
        "DaysSinceStartSite": DaysSinceStartSite,
        "GetRegUsersCount":   GetRegUsersCount,
        "GetDbSize":          GetDbSize,
        "CountFilesByEXT":    CountFilesByEXT,
        "getCurTime":         getCurTime,
    }

    r.SetFuncMap(funcMap)
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    InitRoutes(r)
}

As I understand it, methods should not be included in the function map. I don't understand what my mistake is.
I was reading the documentation and saw the syntax .Field1.Key1.Method1.Field2.Key2.Key2.Method2, that's what I use
